# How can change the class of tags in date input in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, datetime, twitter-bootstrap, formhelper

[image]

as you see the class of datetime input is as class of other inputs. i used twitter bootstrap
but how can change the datetime input internal inputs classes? (without hacking the form helper)

this is my datetime picker input:

```
echo $this->Form->input('issue_date');
```

and the form created like this :

```
echo $this->Form->create('Certificate',array('class'=>'form-horizontal','inputDefaults' => array(
    'format' => array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'error', 'after'),
    'div' => array('class' => 'control-group'),
    'label' => array('class' => 'control-label'),
    'between' => '<div class="controls">',
    'after' => '</div>',
    'error' => array('attributes' => array('wrap' => 'span', 'class' => 'help-inline')))
));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine.

```
echo $this->Form->input('issue_date', array('class' => 'your class name'));
```

the above will generate output like this

```
<div class="input datetime">
    <select name="data[Certificate][issue_date][month]" class="your class name" id="CertificateIssueDateMonth">
        // options
    </select>-
    <select name="data[Certificate][issue_date][day]" class="your class name" id="CertificateIssueDateDay">
        // options
    </select>-
    <select name="data[Certificate][issue_date][year]" class="your class name" id="CertificateIssueDateYear">
        // options
    </select>
    <select name="data[Certificate][issue_date][hour]" class="your class name" id="CertificateIssueDateHour">
    </select>:
    <select name="data[Certificate][issue_date][min]" class="your class name" id="CertificateIssueDateMin">
        // options
    </select>
    <select name="data[Certificate][issue_date][meridian]" class="your class name" id="CertificateIssueDateMeridian">
        // options
    </select>
</div>
```